# Keycloak API execute-actions-email sending http email

Tags: keycloak

I'm running Keycloak and it works great. The only thing I'd like to change is when the `execute-actions-email` API is called it sends the email but the link uses HTTP. I'd like it to be HTTPS. How does KC determine it should use HTTP? Is it because I made the API call over HTTP to trigger the request? Doe it get it from the client config?

Answer (score 1):

It uses whatever protocol was used to make the RESTfull call; just connect to KC on port 8443 (default SSL port) and it'll send the email with a link that uses HTTPS.